# Online syncing Windows 10 Calendar

Tags: windows-10, calendar

My Windows 10 Pro machine was originally setup with ONLY a local account.
I have a number of entries in the Calendar and cannot find a way to backup those entries. So I created a Microsoft account on Outlook.com and added the account to the Calendar on the machine.
What I would like to happen is for all the entries in the Calendar to be saved online on Outlook.com so that if I re-install Windows the Calendar entries will not be lost.
So far the entries do not appear on Outlook.com.
Will this work? If not, is there any way to backup the Windows 10 Calendar entries or export them so I do not lose the entries when I re-install Windows 10?

Comment: I would imagine the only to accomplish this is to modify the calendar association with the events themselves.  That would involve editing each event and changing which calendar it's linked to

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but how would you do that? What are the steps needed making the event linked to the Microsoft account?

Comment: You should be able to choose which calendar the event should be connected to by editing the event.

Comment: Sorry, that is not an option in the Edit window.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I will have to save all my current entries, maybe as screenshots (for re-entry later) and after I re-install Windows I will use a different calendar program, either online or Thunderbird where the data is not hidden.